# Get Shortcode output to database for static post_content

Tags: plugins, php, functions, shortcode, database

my simple shortcode retrieves a list of articles as text files from a folder. These articles are in html format (with h2, p ...). I use a plugin which creates the pages I need on the fly in which I insert my shortcode.
The shortcode works well and the html rendering is ok in the articles, BUT:

**the problem**: the shortcode updates with each page load and makes different content each time.

What do you think is the method to "fix" this because I can't? I tried to write the content of the shortcode in the database in post_content? And remove the shortcode from the articles to be able to edit them later in wordpress. I have made several attempts but nothing, thank you for your help

```
function my_shortcode(){

    $path_to_myplugin = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/my_plugin_name/';
    $thema_folder = "themafolder";
    $passage = fopen($path_to_myplugin.'nbr-init.txt', 'r+');//Stock passage, Start to 0
    $number_passage = fgets($passage); // Read the first line
    $number_passage += 1; // +1
    fseek($passage, 0); // cursor at start of file
    fputs($passage, $number_passage); // Rewrite the new number
    fclose($passage);
    @$file_name = $thema_folder."/"."art-".$thema_folder."-".$number_passage.".txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($path_to_myplugin.$file_name);// Ok it works 

// I try to write the shortcode to the post_content but not working:
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert{
        $args = array(
            'post_content' => $content
        )
    };
$content = wp_insert_post( $args );

    return $content;
}

add_shortcode ('myshortcode', 'my_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have currently is going to create a new post rather than update the post where the shortcode is in use. In order to update the post, you'll need to 
include its ID ([see the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)).

Here's how you can update your code to include the ID:

```php
global $post; // Use the global $post object for the current post.
$args = array(
    'ID'           => $post->ID,
    'post_content' => $content,
);
wp_insert_post( $args ); // Update the current post with the $content.

return $content;
```

I also removed the `$wpdb` usage because you don't need to access the database directly; the `wp_insert_post` function will take care of it for you.

---

**Note:** I've focused this answer on just the part of the code that I think is failing you. I'm not convinced the shortcode approach is an ideal solution (for instance, it might be better to write a simple plugin that loops through your files and creates all the post entries one time). However, I hope this answer helps you achieve your goal right now; there's always the opportunity to optimize as needed.

Comment: thanks for response and all informations! It works, but partially. It's strange, some articles render html as well and therefore remove the shortcode, but not for all. I noticed that by reloading the page several times or by clearing the cache, in some cases the html ends up being written in the base. Any idea?

Comment: If you've got a caching plugin enabled (or your host caches), it's likely going to be a challenge to track down the issue. You may need to resort to a more active approach to populate the database if it's not practical to wait until it eventually happens.

Comment: I understand, Thank you. I'm not using a cache plugin. Your solution work perfectly without the third party plugin i use to generate. With the generation plugin, my shortcode replace his content instead of add the content (a part generate by the plugin) > but i think it's another problem.  So many thanks for your help, it help me a lot.